# How to Customize Shopify Account Page to Include Separate Tabs for Account Details and Subscriptions?

Tags: json, shopify, e-commerce, liquid, shopify-template

I'm currently working on customizing the account page of my Shopify store and faced a challenge that I hope some of you might help me with. My goal is to enhance the user experience by dividing the account page into two distinct tabs: one for the usual account details and another dedicated to managing subscriptions.

Here's what I aim to achieve:

Account Tab: This tab will contain all the standard account information and settings that a user can edit (e.g., personal info, address, password).
Subscriptions Tab: A separate tab where users can view and manage their subscriptions, including options to cancel, pause, or modify their existing subscriptions.

I have a basic understanding of Shopify's theme structure and know that Liquid is used for theme customization. However, I'm not sure which specific files I should be focusing on to implement this dual-tab functionality. Additionally, I'm curious if there are any existing plugins or Shopify apps that could simplify this process, or if it's something that needs to be custom coded.